# PHOAS in Coq: type mismatch

Tags: coq

I'm transcribing in Coq the (informal) definitions from the [2008 PHOAS paper](http://adam.chlipala.net/papers/PhoasICFP08/PhoasICFP08.pdf), section 2.1.

```
Inductive tm' {V : Set} : Set :=
| Var : V -> tm'
| App : tm' -> tm' -> tm'
| Abs : (V -> tm') -> tm'.

Definition tm := forall X, @tm' X.

Fail Example id : tm := Abs Var.
```

Output:

```
The term "Abs Var" has type "tm'" while it is expected to have type "tm".
```

That's rather obnoxious. How can I make this code type-check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code that works:

```
Example id : tm := fun _ => Abs Var.
```

The issue is that you were trying to construct a function (something of type `forall`) without a lambda (`fun`).

Answer (score 0):

```
Example id : tm := fun (X : Set) => Abs Var.
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16533671)

Comment: As you can see from Jason Gross' answer, this is indeed a complete answer.